# Use Autolayout Not Checked, Still get constraint errors

Tags: autolayout

I do not use autolayout. My app is incredibly dynamic, in that users can drag fields onto a canvas to create forms. Therefore, I have developed my own routines to render my xibs on any device in either portrait or landscape. To do this, I make sure the Use Autolayout is not checked for the xib's view in the file inspector. In fact none of the boxes are checked (trait variations, safe area, etc). However, I continue to get constraint errors. Is this just a bug. My code works perfectly but it is quite annoying to get the plethora of warnings in the output window. This just started in the last release or two. I am using XCode 9.2 with a deployment target of iOS 11.

Comment: Are you simply setting the `.frame` property of your objects? Can you show an example of a warning you are getting? If you are not setting any constraints, it seem rather odd that you are getting constraint conflicts...

Comment: Yes, setting the frame's for all views. You can create logic with the app to hide fields, disable them etc. It would be a nightmare to try and use autolayout, my routines are more efficient too.

Comment: Seems odd that you're getting constraint errors without using auto layout... Are your views' positions / sizes being changed due to the constraint errors? Can you replicate that in a new, simple project?